# problem with creating a graph using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I have a little problem. I have create with latex a graph. Here is my code

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzset{every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white}}

  \node[state]         (A)              {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (B) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below=of B] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below=of C] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (F) [right=of B] {$A_{2}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (E) [above=of F] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (G) [below=of F] {$A_{1}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (H) [below=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (J) [right=of F] {$A_{2}(m-1)$};
  \node[state]         (I) [above=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (K) [below=of J] {$A_{1}(m-1)$};
  \node[state]         (L) [below=of K] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (M) [right=of J] {$A_{2}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (N) [right=of K] {$A_{1}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (O) [above=of M] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (P) [below=of N] {$\{\omega\}$};


  \path (B) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (A)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (B)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (C)
        (C) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (C)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (D)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (F)
        (F) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (E)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (F)
            edge              node(aux) {$\QAto$}                        (G)
        (G) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (G)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (H)
        (J) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (I)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (K)
        (K) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (K)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (L)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (M)
        (M) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (M)
            edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (O)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (N)
        (N) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (N)
            edge              node {$\QAow + \QAot\mathbf{1}$}      (P);
 \node[right=2mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\caption{\"Ubergangsgraph von $X$}\label{Abbildung3}
\end{figure}
```

where

```
\newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
\newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
\newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}
```

The graph looks as follows

[image]

My question is how I can use ovals instead of cirlces, such that the nodes all have the same size. It should look like as follows
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this either mean that the font becomes super tiny or you clip away some text? Wouldn't it be better to either change notation (e.g. `A_1^{(m-1)}`) or to make the other blobs bigger?

Comment: How can I make the circles to ovals? This would solve it

Comment: Just load `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` and change `circle` to `ellipse`.

Comment: But in my code there is no parameter to use ovals instead of circles

Comment: Well, you do not disclose all information. `circle` is hidden in the definition of `state`. Try `\tikzset{every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white,ellipse}}`.

Comment: it works! But how can I shrink the graph sucht that fits on the page. Here is the result

Comment: Please consider to accept an answer. You can do so, by clinking on the check mark.

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is not solved. Can you post a solution to my problem?

Comment: As I understand, the question is solved (oval instead of round). If you have additional questions, then post a new separate question with a minimal but complete code example. At least, this is the expected approach here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mostly off-topic, but it can be helpful:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
\newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
\newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
%   scale=0.8,
%   transform shape,
node distance = 15mm and 35mm, on grid,
  start chain = going below,
 state/.style = {ellipse, minimum height=7mm, inner xsep=0pt,
                 fill=red, text=white,
                 on chain},
every edge/.append style = {draw,-Stealth},
every loop/.append style = {looseness=4}
                        ]
\begin{scope}[every node/.style = {state}]
  \node (A) {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node (B) {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node (C) {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node (D) {$\{\omega\}$};
%
  \node (E) [right=of A]    {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node (F) {$A_{2}(2)$};
  \node (G) {$A_{1}(2)$};
  \node (H) {$\{\omega\}$};
%
  \node (I) [right=of E]    {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node (J) {$A_{2}(m{-}1)$};
  \node (K) {$A_{1}(m{-}1)$};
  \node (L) {$\{\omega\}$};
%
  \node (M) [right=of I]    {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node (N) {$A_{2}(m)$};
  \node (O) {$A_{1}(m)$};
  \node (P) {$\{\omega\}$};
\end{scope}
%
\path   (B) edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$"] (A)
            edge [loop left,"$\QAt$"]               (B)
            edge ["$\QAto$"]                        (C)
        (C) edge [loop left,"$\QAo$"]               (C)
            edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$"] (D)
            edge ["$\QAot$" ']                      (F)
        (F) edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$"] (E)
            edge [loop left,"$\QAt$"]               (F)
            edge    node (aux) {$\QAto$}            (G)
        (G) edge [loop left,"$\QAo$"]               (G)
            edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$"] (H)
        (J) edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$"] (I)
            edge [loop left,,"$\QAt$"]              (J)
            edge ["$\QAto$"]                        (K)
        (K) edge [loop left,"$\QAo$"]               (K)
            edge ["$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$"] (L)
            edge ["$\QAot$" ']                      (N)
        (M) edge [loop left,"$\QAt$"]               (M)
            edge ["$\QAtw$"]                        (N)
        (N) edge ["$\QAto$"]                        (O)
        (O) edge [loop left,"$\QAo$"]               (O)
            edge ["$\QAow + \QAot\mathbf{1}$"]      (P);
\draw[ultra thick,loosely dotted,shorten <=2mm] (aux) -- + (1.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

i don't know, if this image isn't wide than `\textwidth` since the page layout of your document is unknown. however, you can adjust image width with uncomment lines with `scale=...` and `transform shape` and adjust image size accordingly :-)

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment. `ellipse` does work. To decrease the horizontal space, I changed the `looseness` of the loops, decreased the `node distance` and stacked the lower right edge label. Note also that the loops increase the bounding box unnecessarily such that I add a bounding box by hand. (With the lower looseness of the loops the problem is less severe.) To make the wider ellipses approximately equal, you could play with `inner xsep`. Alternatively, you could use `\makebox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,automata,positioning} 
\newcommand{\QAt}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAo}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAot}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}A_{2}}}
\newcommand{\QAto}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}A_{1}}}
\newcommand{\QAtC}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}C}}
\newcommand{\QAtw}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}}
\newcommand{\QAow}{\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2cm,
                    semithick,
 every state/.append style={fill=red,draw=none,text=white,ellipse},
 every loop/.append style={looseness=5}]
  \path[use as bounding box] (-2.7,0.45) rectangle (15,-10.65); 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{(width("$A_{2}(m-1)$")-width("$A_{2}(1)$"))/4}
  \node[state]         (A)              {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (B) [below=of A] {$A_{2}(1)$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (C) [below=of B] {$A_{1}(1)$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below=of C] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (F) [right=of B] {$A_{2}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (E) [above=of F] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (G) [below=of F] {$A_{1}(2)$};
  \node[state]         (H) [below=of G] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=-\mywidth]         (J) [right=of F] {$A_{2}(m-1)$};
  \node[state]         (I) [above=of J] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=-\mywidth]         (K) [below=of J] {$A_{1}(m-1)$};
  \node[state]         (L) [below=of K] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (M) [right=of J] {$A_{2}(m)$};
  \node[state,inner xsep=\mywidth]         (N) [right=of K] {$A_{1}(m)$};
  \node[state]         (O) [above=of M] {$\{\omega\}$};
  \node[state]         (P) [below=of N] {$\{\omega\}$};


  \path (B) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (A)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (B)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (C)
        (C) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (C)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (D)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (F)
        (F) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (E)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (F)
            edge              node(aux) {$\QAto$}                        (G)
        (G) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (G)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (H)
        (J) edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{2}\{\omega\}}$} (I)
            edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (J)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (K)
        (K) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (K)
            edge              node {$\mathbf{Q}_{A_{1}\{\omega\}}$} (L)
            edge [right]      node {$\QAot$}                        (M)
        (M) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAt$}                         (M)
            edge              node {$\QAtw$}                        (O)
            edge              node {$\QAto$}                        (N)
        (N) edge [loop left]  node {$\QAo$}                         (N)
            edge              node[align=left] {$\hphantom{+}\QAow$\\
            $+ \QAot\mathbf{1}$}      (P);
 \node[right=2mm of aux,font=\bfseries\Huge]{\dots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\"Ubergangsgraph von $X$.}\label{Abbildung3}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but it dont fit on the page. How can you decrease the graph?

Comment: @wayne I added some changes that decrease the width.

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to decrease (m-1) such that the corresponding nodes have all the same size like the original picture I have added at the top

Comment: @wayne Sure. There are (at least) two possibilities: either play with `inner xsep` or use `\makebox`es. I added a solution that uses the first option.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!

Comment: +1: @waybe It would probably be much easier if you would provide a complete example that one can compile. This minimizes iterative guesswork.